# I am unable to get rid of extra charecters with comments in SQL injection payload

Tags: sql-injection

I am practicing SQL injection with DVWA, but for some reason the server keeps giving me an error even when I comment out extra `'`.

For example, here is what I inputed in my website:

```
http://localhost/DVWA/vulnerabilities/sqli/?id=' OR SLEEP(5) AND 'a'='a' /*
```

But for some reason it still gives me an error even when I comment out all of the extra characters as shown in the URL when I used the `/*`. It keeps giving me the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'aaa'='aaa' /* ''` at line 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. After hours of testing, and retrying I found that by using the # I was able to comment out all of my extra characters

Answer (score 0):

The characters `/*` open a C style comment, but when the SQL parser cannot find the associated end of the comment `*/`, it will not treat this as a comment.

Use a native SQL style comment `--` (Dash Dash Space) which is implicitly closed by the next newline.

Comment: That didn't work either, but I did find the solution I just used the # instead to comment out extra characters, but thanks for the help :)